# echo two table from database in one time

Tags: php, mysql

this is my code to echo one table . anybody can tell how echo two table in same db ?

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $tem = $row;

        $json = json_encode($tem);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo $json;
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM t1";
 $sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM t2";


  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $result_1 = $conn->query($sql_1);

  if ($result->num_rows >0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $tem = $row;
  $json = json_encode($tem);
  $a1 = rtrim($json , ']');

  }
  } else {
  echo "0 results";
  }

 if ($result_1->num_rows >0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row_1[] = $result_1->fetch_assoc()) {

  $tem_1 = $row_1;

  $json_1 = json_encode($tem_1);

  $a2 = ltrim($json_1 , '[');

  } 

 } else {
 echo "0 results";
 }

 echo $a1 , ',' ;
 echo $a2 ;
 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You only emit one row, right? The problem is that you overwrite `$json` again and again, for each row. This should work better:

```
<?php
// as before

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$rows = array();

while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: I would just suggest putting the braces on the loop. You gain no performance from leaving them off and open your code up to errors because if you forget to add them when more logic is added to the loop if will not execute correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking about 2 tables so I assume you want another query to run and then also echo out some json.

Since json is being echoed I assume this might be via an ajax call which you cannot echo twice in.

If those assumptions are correct and there is literally no extra processing on a row in those while loops then the most direct way to do what you are asking is with `fetch_all()` and another query:

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//Table1 query and fetch_all give an array back
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$table1 = $result->fetch_all();

//Table2 and fetch_all give an array back
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table2";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$table2 = $result->fetch_all();

//Send json of both in one line
echo $json_encode(array($table1,$table2));

//Check on other side if it is empty. That is more view related.
```